# JPA Criteria count + isMember generates wrong sql

Tags: sql, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

I'm trying to build the following query with JPA Criteria API (Eclipselink):

```
    final CriteriaBuilder qb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = qb.createQuery(Long.class);
    final Root<ProblemBean> problem = cq.from(ProblemBean.class);
    cq.select(qb.countDistinct(problem));
    cq.where(qb.or(qb.equal(problem.get(ProblemBean_.mainUserLv), user),  qb.isMember(user, problem.get(ProblemBean_.usersLv))));
    return this.em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
```

Basically, I want wo check if there is at least one `ProblemBean` which has the given user as `mainUserLv` or as member of `usersLv` collection.
The generated SQL code is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(t0.ID)) FROM T_PROBLEM t0, T_PROBLEM_USER t2, T_USER t1 
WHERE (((t0.ID_USER_LV = ?) OR (t1.ID = ?)) AND 
         ((t2.ID_PROBLEM = t0.ID) AND (t1.ID = t2.ID_USER)))
```

Needless to say this returns always 0.
I would expect the following SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(t0.ID)) FROM T_PROBLEM t0, T_PROBLEM_USER t2, T_USER t1 
WHERE ((t0.ID_USER_LV = ?) OR 
        ((t1.ID = ?) AND ((t2.ID_PROBLEM = t0.ID) AND (t1.ID = t2.ID_USER))))
```

Is this a Eclipselink bug or do I miss something?